# Installing QGIS Server on existing Apache/PHP on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, php, qgis-server, apache

Using OSGeo4W installer, I installed QGIS server while having already Apache/PHP on my computer. And I got this message: `The requested URL was not found on this server` when I tested the QGIS Server configuration by typing:

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

This is the tutorial I followed: https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/how-to-install-qgis-server-in-windows-10/

After installing QGIS server and configuring the `httpd.conf` as instructed in that tutorial, and also going through various FAQ on the related matter as well, I couldn't fix the problem and still have that error message.

Here is my `httpd.conf` file with the changes made:

```
Define SRVROOT "C:\Webserver\Apache24"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 8080

ServerAdmin admin@localhost

ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied </Directory>

DocumentRoot "C:\Webserver\Apache24\htdocs"

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"> <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html </IfModule>

ScriptAlias /qgis-ltr/ "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin"

<Directory "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin">    SetHandler fcgi-script
    AllowOverride All
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted </Directory> AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .exe

Include conf/extra/httpd_qgis.conf

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

PHPIniDir "C:/Webserver/php7" LoadModule php7_module "C:/Webserver/php7/php7apache2_4.dll" AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

LoadFile "C:/Webserver/php7/libpq.dll"

SetEnv GDAL_DATA "C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal" SetEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\resources" SetEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37" SetEnv PYTHONPATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts" SetEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem” SetEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr" SetEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt4\plugins"

RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^/proxy/(.+)$ /gisapp/admin/qgisproxy.php?map=$1.qgs [QSA,PT] RewriteRule ^/gisapp/([^\.]+)$ /gisapp/index.php [PT]
```

Apache Version: Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.7;
QGIS Desktop and QGIS Server version 3.14.15;
QGIS-LTR-Server version 3.10.9

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail, please [edit vyour question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/373312/edit).  What tutorials/FAQ? Include urls please. What exactly did you do to configure your httpd.conf? Include relevant sections (as text) please. Did you configure your virtual hosts? Include relevant sections (as text) please.  Have you checked the logs? Include relevant log entries (as text) please.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message, just a URL.  Please [Edit] the Question to contain the error message *as text*.